# Pikabu Menu iOS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

On this site: http://www.carrollhs.org/s/1253/start.aspx

If you are on an iOS device, if you click on the mobile button the rest of the links do not show.  If you reload the page then click the button all links display.

I've checked github, and tried the latest version of pikabu with the same results.  If seems like pikabu is calculating the height of the window rather than the height of the menu.  I have been trying to have it find the height of the document instead with no luck.

Comment: By 'mobile button', you mean the menu button right ?

Comment: It works on my iPhone after clicking on articles. But never in the home page. I don't know Pikabu but I see the project in github and it's a javascript framework.Try to put some alert() function or log something in the method called (as I see, it should be 'openSidebar') to know if you get into the method...if so, go on with logging and debugging. Send us some logs then...